# How to set a post featured image from an already made custom field

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

So I migrated a website of a webdesigner and he used for news-posts a custom field for images. Now I made this website and I need to change 256 posts to set a featured image since it's not working with this custom field. Does anyone know how to set a post featured image from an already made custom field?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear, but I suppose your new theme is using featured images in the normal way, which leaves empty featured images on older posts, because they are stored in a custom field. You can catch those using the filter at the end of [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/). Because I don't know how the custom field is made I can't give complete code, but it would look like this:

```
add_filter ('post_thumbnail_html','wpse303106_custom_featured_image',10,5);

function wpse303106_custom_featured_image ($html, $post->ID, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr) {
  if ('' == $html && test-for-existence-of-custom-field) {
    $html = ... assemble from custom field ...
    }
  return $html;
  }
```

Comment: Can't speak dutch in here right? well this is the old website: https://vledder.nu/category/nieuws/  I dont even know what custom field it's using. Underneath 'Nieuws' there are different images, I need the images on the left of the news as the new featured image in the posts for example.

Comment: From the site I can't see the code that is generating the custom field. You'll have to ask the old developer. Building the filter shouldn't be more than 15 minutes work or so.